# Struts 1.1 logic iterator over an ArrayList of objects

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, struts, javabeans

I've got an ArrayList of  objects that I read from a txt file, RegistrationFormBean(); is the element type

```
    public List getuserList() throws IOException{

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream("log.txt");

                int i=0;

                String temp[]=new String[5];

                                          tmp= new RegistrationFormBean();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));

                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                              StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"\t\t");

                    while(st.hasMoreElements()){
                    temp[i]=st.nextElement().toString();
                                                }

                                                   tmp.setName(temp[0]);
                    tmp.setCognome(temp[1]);
                    tmp.setCitta(temp[4]);
                    tmp.setDdnascita(temp[2]);
                    tmp.setCodfisc(temp[3]);

                    userList.add(tmp);
                                        }
                in.close();

    return userList;
}
```

this is the jsp page that should iterate over the arraylist returned and print the attributes for each element of the arraylist

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld"   prefix="bean" %>
<jsp:useBean id="userList" scope="request" class="com.webagesolutions.struts.actions.query"/>



<html:html>
<HEAD>
<%@ page 
language="java"
contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
%>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META name="GENERATOR" content="IBM WebSphere Studio">
<META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<LINK href="theme/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <table border=1>
        <logic:iterate name="userList" id="nextElement" property="userList">
    <tr>
    <td><bean:write name="nextelement" property="name"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="nextElement" property="cognome"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="nextElement" property="ddnascita"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="nextElement" property="codfisc"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="nextElement" property="citta"/></td>  
    </tr>
    </logic:iterate>        
    </table>
</BODY>
</html:html>
```

So I'm wondering how to access the elements of next element, suppose that the property are the element.name element.cognome element.ddnascita (attributes of element), should I define some getters in the class that reads the txt file ? 
should I reference the element type in the jsp page ?

note that with the code I've wrote I get only the first column printed and it contains the "citta" wich in my tmp is the last attribute of the element,
also I've did a debug and the list gets loaded correctly so the problem I suppose is in the jsp page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<nested:nest>` tag to access nested properties.
To use it, you need to add the taglib in the JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-nested" prefix="nested"%>
```

For the above example, you have `userList` as list of the parent beans, which has some composite properties like `cognome` and plain String properties like `name`. Now, start iterating the `userList` like this:

```
<nested:nest property="userList">
    <!-- 'name' is just plain String, does not need a nested iteration --> 
    <nested:write property="name"/> 

    <!-- but 'cognome' has some inner properties, we are interested in exploring -->
    <nested:iterate property="cognome">
         <nested:write property="somePropertyOfCognome"/>
    </nested:iterate>

</nested:nest>
```

Comment: thx that is what I was looking for, beside the apache page where can I find some decent reference regarding the custom struts tags ?